# Unexpected result determining coordinates on a nested (grid) array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a nested array representing an "image" (a map of 0's and 1's). My end goal is to transform the 4 numbers surrounding any "1" to also be 1's.

The approach I've taken is to map the x,y coordinates of any existing 1 in the initial grid and add those coordinates to a new array so I can later use them to perform the transformation on the original.

To simplify, I'm trying to get this to work, initially, on an array that includes only one "1" — however, the result is unexpected in that it's storing multiple sets of x,y coordinates for the one "1" in the array, instead of a single set. I'm sure the solution is simple, but as a beginner, I'm stumped as to why this is happening.

(Please ignore the commented code; it's the beginnings of the transformation, but I'll bring it back once I solve this issue.)

```
class Image
def initialize(image)
    @image = image
end

def output_image
    x_size = @image.first.length
    y_size = @image.length


    edit = []
    @image.each_with_index do | row , y |
        row.each_with_index do |cell, x |
            edit << [x,y] if cell == 1
        end
        # edit.each do |pair|   
        #   x = pair.first
        #   y = pair.last
        #       @image[x-1][y] = 1 if x > 0 
        #       @image[x+1][y] = 1 if x < (x_size - 1)
        #       @image[x][y-1] = 1 if y > 0
        #       @image[x][y+1] = 1 if y < (y_size - 1)
        # end
        puts edit.inspect
        #puts @image.inspect
        # @image.each { |x| puts x.join }
    end
end
end

image = Image.new([
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ])
image.output_image
```

This results in:

```
[]
[[2, 1]]
[[2, 1]]
[[2, 1]]
```

Rather than the expected:

```
[]
[[2,1]]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing the edit variable before each run of the outer loop. So each time you print it, it's still storing the initial coordinate where you found a 1.

You'll get the expected result if you insert `edit = []` after `puts edit.inspect`.

This does what you want:

```
def output_image
    x_size = @image.first.length
    y_size = @image.length
    edit = []
    @image.each_with_index do | row , y |
        row.each_with_index do |cell, x |
            edit << [x,y] if cell == 1
        end
    end
    edit.each do |pair|   
        y = pair.first
        x = pair.last
        @image[x-1][y] = 1 if x > 0 
        @image[x+1][y] = 1 if x < (x_size - 1)
        @image[x][y-1] = 1 if y > 0
        @image[x][y+1] = 1 if y < (y_size - 1)
    end
    @image.each { |x| puts x.join }
    puts edit.inspect
end
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question then... I only included `puts edit.inspect` so that I could see what the result was because the transformation (the commented code) wasn't acting as I expected...

I expected the code above to result in an output of 
0010
0111
0010
0000

Instead I get something very different.

Comment: Try this: move all of the commented code outside of both loops (so you're not adding new 1s while you're searching for them), then flip the `x` and `y` variables in the `edit.each` loop (since the y variable indexes which array the x variable index is in, the former is first). Edited the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Rob... That points out a mistake I had made earlier (by flipping the x & y in the each_with_index loops above). I'm still getting four arrays output where I expected one...

Comment: if you want to consolidate the 4 arrays into 1 array of 16 values, you could add a call to `.flatten!` after your `.each`/`.join` block

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for bearing with a beginner! I had a loop in the wrong place, so it was looping back through the methods too many times. Was looking for an output of `0010
0111
0010
0000`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again to Rob for the help. This was the solution I was looking for:

```
def output_image
        x_size = @image.first.length
        y_size = @image.length


        edit = []
        @image.each_with_index do | row , x |
            row.each_with_index do |cell, y |
                edit << [x,y] if cell == 1
            end
        end
        edit.each do |x,y|  
                @image[x-1][y] = 1 if x > 0 
                @image[x+1][y] = 1 if x < (x_size - 1)
                @image[x][y-1] = 1 if y > 0
                @image[x][y+1] = 1 if y < (y_size - 1)
        end

        @image.each { |x| puts x.join }
end
```